# Following jQuery isn't working. Take a look

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Code:**

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="back">Back</a>
    <div class="outer"></div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="back">Back</a>
    <div class="outer"></div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $('.next').prev().animate({
        scrollLeft: '+=150'
    }, 200);
});
$('.back').click(function() {
    $('.back').next().animate({
        scrollLeft: '-=150'
    }, 200);
});
```

Error:
Basically I have more codes with the same classes as above and I want to scroll the code which is clicked. But the code written above scroll all the ".outer" on the page. Each set of the code is in different div. The inside material of the "outer" isn't provided which is scroll able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Use `$(this)` for get current Object

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().animate({ scrollLeft: '+=150'}, 200);
});

$('.back').click(function () {
    $(this).next().animate({ scrollLeft: '-=150'}, 200);
});
```

Comment: @JahanzaibAsgher  Glad it helps

Comment: Gave me a very simple way. Thanks a lot once again. It works for me

Comment: '.next()' and '.prev()' has been repeated twice by error.

Answer (score 4):

You need to execute the code using current element context i.e. `this`. Also animate the siblings of parent element so traverse up using `$(this).closest('div')` then use `.prev()` or `next()`

```
$(function() {
    $('.next').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('div').prev().animate({
            scrollLeft: '+=150'
        }, 200);
    });
    $('.back').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('div').next().animate({
            scrollLeft: '-=150'
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to wrap your code in a document ready function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next').click(function () {
        $(this).prev().animate({ scrollLeft: '+=150'}, 200);
    });
    $('.back').click(function () {
        $(this).next().animate({ scrollLeft: '-=150'}, 200);
    });
});
</script>
```

Also using the on method is better for event binding, e.g.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next').on('click', function () {
        $(this).prev().animate({ scrollLeft: '+=150'}, 200);
    });
    $('.back').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next().animate({ scrollLeft: '-=150'}, 200);
    });
});
</script>
```

Edit:

As @GuruprasadRao pointed out, I'm assuming you are already but make sure you're using a HTML5 doctype otherwise you'll need to add type="text/javascript" to your script tag.

Comment: Also don't forget to mention `script type`.. ;)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Doesn't need type if using a HTML5 doctype.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Not having a type attribute is perfectly standards compliant if you are using a HTML5 doctype. It's actually quite useless.

Comment: I use HTML5. Thanks for you attention.